# First draw results from Express Entry pool - Canada

Tags: canada, immigration, resident-permit

I learnt that first draw of Express Entry pool(Canada) will happen in last week of Jan.

Looks like Canada immigration process is not as strong/stable as New Zealand immigration process in terms of schedules and Quality of processing the VISA requests.

Is there any change in the plan/schedule for first draw from Express Entry pool(Canada)?

Comment: What plan? Do you mean if Canada plans to delay the first draw or...? Right now I think your question is unclear.

Comment: @mkennedy schedule plan for first draw

Comment: 'Plans to make first draw' and announcing first draw, in my opinion, are different. I don't see any draws as of now

Comment: @mkennedy Many new users are updating their questions as answer instead of comments. How do we handle this?

Comment: You put a comment after the answer asking them to take the tour and that this is not the usual "forum" site. You can flag an inappropriate answer for the moderators.

Comment: @mkennedy I do not know the option, How do I flag to moderator?

Comment: Right below the tags in a question, or below an answer. Both on the left side, there should be medium gray share | edit | flag links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first draw have already taken place. If you have 886 points or more you're in!
See Ministerial instruction below:**

Ministerial Instructions respecting invitations to apply for permanent residence under the Express Entry system #1 – January 31, 2015 11:59:48 UTC

The Minister of Citizenship and Immigration, pursuant to section 10.3 of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act, gives the annexed Ministerial Instructions Respecting Invitations to Apply for Permanent Residence under the Express Entry System (January 31, 2015).

Ottawa, January 31, 2015

CHRIS ALEXANDER
Minister of Citizenship and Immigration

MINISTERIAL INSTRUCTIONS RESPECTING INVITATIONS TO APPLY FOR PERMANENT RESIDENCE UNDER THE EXPRESS ENTRY SYSTEM (January 31, 2015)

Determination — number of invitations

1. (1) For the purposes of paragraph 10.2(1)(b) of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act, the number of invitations that may be issued during the period beginning on January 31, 2015 and ending on February 1, 2015 is 779.

Required rank

(2) Foreign nationals who, on January 31, 2015 at 11:59:48 UTC, have been assigned a total of 886 points or more under the Comprehensive Ranking System that is set out in the Ministerial Instructions Respecting the Express Entry System, as published in the Canada Gazette, Part I, on December 1, 2014 and as amended from time to time, occupy the rank required to be invited to make an application for permanent residence.

here is the [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/mi/) for the above info